# Is there a dump file created when Flash application crashes in browser?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, firefox, adobe, flashdevelop

I'm trying to debug my flash application and when I build and run it in debug(in FlashDevelop), it crashes. Is there a dump file which can give me information about what caused the crash?

Answer (score 1):

There is no dump file, but you can install the debug version of the flash player, and it will display the error type and, when possible the function call that was last called whent he error occurred.

you can get the flash debug player here:
http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html

Once you have the flash debug player installed, flash will write all trace comments and erors to the flashlog.txt of your flash player install. On windows its found here:
C:/users/USERNAME/AppData/Roaming/Macromedia/Flash Player/flashlog.txt

By the way - is it flashdevelop, or the flash standalone player that is crashing?
You may want to try publishing with a different "Test Project" setting in the project settings panel. Try using "Play: FlashViewer default". 
Make sure you are using the debug standalone player.

With that setting, flash will not bring down flashdevelop when it crashes.

Comment: It looks like it had to do with version of Flash player. I compiled into version 10.1 but had flash debug player 11.1. When I install flash debug 10.3, it doesn't crash.

Comment: This is a flash debug player in a browser. Test Project setting in  FlashDevelop is set to open a document and I specify a URL for my application.

Comment: Also, even when flash player crashes, it doesn't write any information to flashlog :(

Answer (score 0):

If you debug in browser (which one?), it may be helpful to see the crash log of the browser. It's difficult to find any of them on every platform... but here, eventually, I knew where the Firefox logging goes http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_crashes#Crash_reports it isn't really straight forward, and you need to read the article to understand how to get hold of the information.

I would imagine, however, that if you ran the browser from the console, then it's stdout would be redirected into console - not sure, how much that would be helpful, but at least you'd get some info out of it. Like, at least the actual reason that caused it to close, which sometimes may provide some info, but some other time would be just a "pure virtual function call" or "memory segmentation fault" with no further info.

Not sure what alternative you have on Windows, there's Unix trace utility that can trace all system calls while an application is running - could capture a lot of noise, but could be useful just as well.

Finally, you could try to test your code stepping in the debugger. Even though you probably won't reach the code that causes the error, you might get quite close to limit yourself to fewer options to check.